# PHP root path instead of relative path for localhost

Tags: php, html, localhost, root

Hello I am having an issue on directory paths on my localhost. I would like to be able to use a root path with php similar to html this is what i have

HTML Root Path:

```
/~Damian/home/
```

PHP

```
 // generates random images for slideshow
$dir = "../pics"; //set path to images
$thumbDir = "../pics"; //set path to image thumbnails
$numberToDisplay = 17; //number of images to display

if ($handle = opendir($thumbDir)) { 
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
        if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
           preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.JPG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/', $file)){
            $files[] = $file;
           }
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
$i = 0;
$images = array_rand(array_flip($files), $numberToDisplay);
while ($i < $numberToDisplay){
    echo "<div><img src='$thumbDir/$images[$i]' width='320' height='240' alt='random image' /></div>";
$i++;
}
```

and lastly this is what i would like to do but can't seem to figure it out:

```
// generates random images for slideshow
$dir = "/~Damian/home/pics"; //set path to images
$thumbDir = "/~Damian/home/pics"; //set path to image thumbnails
$numberToDisplay = 17; //number of images to display

if ($handle = opendir($thumbDir)) { 
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
        if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
           preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.JPG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/', $file)){
            $files[] = $file;
           }
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
$i = 0;
$images = array_rand(array_flip($files), $numberToDisplay);
while ($i < $numberToDisplay){
    echo "<div><img src='$thumbDir/$images[$i]' width='320' height='240' alt='random image' /></div>";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Not possible. PHP has no awareness of the URL used to execute the script. It operates at the filesystem level, and sees/uses only filesystem paths. You will have to supply the translations between web-space addresses and filesystem-space addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these:

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/../pathToYourPicsDirectoryFromCurrentScriptLocation";
```

Or

```
define('PATH_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('PATH_PICS',PATH_ROOT."/pics");

// in your script
$dir = PATH_PICS;
```

If you put the second example in a config file that you can include everywhere, your pics directory will always be available under the defined variable PATH_PICS.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the examples worked so this is what i came up with for now

```
<?php
                        if($frontPage=='yes'){
                                // generates random images for slideshow
                                $dir = "pics"; //set path to images
                                $thumbDir = "pics"; //set path to image thumbnails
                                $numberToDisplay = 17; //number of images to display

                                if ($handle = opendir($thumbDir)) { 
                                    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                                        if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                                           preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.JPG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/', $file)){
                                            $files[] = $file;
                                           }
                                    }
                                    closedir($handle); 
                                }
                                $i = 0;
                                $images = array_rand(array_flip($files), $numberToDisplay);
                                while ($i < $numberToDisplay){
                                    echo "<div><img src='$thumbDir/$images[$i]' width='320' height='240' alt='random image' /></div>";
                                $i++;
                                }
                        }
                        else{
                            // generates random images for slideshow
                                $dir = "../pics"; //set path to images
                                $thumbDir = "../pics"; //set path to image thumbnails
                                $numberToDisplay = 17; //number of images to display

                                if ($handle = opendir($thumbDir)) { 
                                    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                                        if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                                           preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.JPG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/', $file)){
                                            $files[] = $file;
                                           }
                                    }
                                    closedir($handle); 
                                }
                                $i = 0;
                                $images = array_rand(array_flip($files), $numberToDisplay);
                                while ($i < $numberToDisplay){
                                    echo "<div><img src='$thumbDir/$images[$i]' width='320' height='240' alt='random image' /></div>";
                                $i++;
                                }
                        }

                                ?>
```